# Upgraded to Mavericks, Changed PATH, Still Not Working

Tags: compiling

I'm using Sublime Text 2 to compile and am receiving this error:

```
Attempted command:latexmk -cd -e $pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O' -f -pdf mentorship program.tex
```

Build engine: Traditional Builder

Before changing the PATH and replacing MacTex 2013 with MacTex 2014, when I attempt to compile, I received .aux and .latexmk, but no PDF. Sublime Text 2 gave me no error before.

Any thoughts?

Edit #1: Reinstalled MacTex. Fixed PATH. Receive:
    [Compiling /Users/williamcobb/Desktop/mentorship program.tex]

TraditionalBuilder: Invoking latexmk... done.

However, no PDF is created.

Edit #2: The TEX Distribution Preference Pane is also broken.

Edit #3: If I try to compile via Sublime Text 2, nothing happens. However, if I compile via TexWorks and then compile via Sublime Text 2, it works, but Skim fails to open the PDF (force closes).

Comment: Can you still compile via the command line?  If so, I'd compare `which` output from the command line and from within  ST.

Comment: I can compile via TeXworks, just not ST.

Comment: Can you tells us what *error message* you get as, currently, you only say what sublime is attempting to do. Also, what happens when you try to run `pdflatex` from a terminal?

Comment: I don't receive any errors from ST. When I run pdflatex from the terminal, I receive:! I can't find file `mentorshipprogram.tex'.
<*> mentorshipprogram.tex

Comment: There may be an issue with the correct specification of the file name. According to the command line version of your compilation attempt, the file's name is `mentorship program.tex` -- note the space. In other places, you say the file's name is `mentorshipprogram.tex` -- *without* a space. Which name is correct, if any?

Comment: @Mico I used the correct name (with a space) and I still receive the same error (in Terminal).